# Re-glue plastic edge banding on a desk

Tags: carpentry, adhesive

I have an office desk with a semi-circular section (to sit at) where the edge banding has come away from the wood. The edge banding is fairly thick (1-1.5mm) and rigid, so it takes a fair bit of pressure to press it back flush against the wood.

I'd like to stick the edge banding back to the desk. What's the best kind of glue for this? Would a hot glue gun be the best solution? Would a series of big bulldog clips be enough to hold it in place while the glue sets?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I have no idea what kind of laminates are typically sold in Japan (where you're at)... In Europe a lot of the laminates have a temperature-activated glue holding them to the particle board, so unless this glue is heavily contaminated with grime etc., it can be reglued with an iron (for clothes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laminate is usually held on with [contact cement](http://www.homedepot.com/p/DAP-3-fl-oz-Weldwood-Original-Contact-Cement-00107/100195615#.UlanhlCKIuc) similar to this

[image: contact cement]

This type of adhesive is spread on both surfaces to be joined, allowed to dry and then pressed together. Pressing firmly with a small wooden roller (or a rolling pin) helps make the bond tight.

It is important to make sure the parts are perfectly aligned before the surfaces touch because they cannot be moved once they contact. This is often done by placing a piece of very smooth paper between the two surfaces while aligning, then sliding it out.

If the band is already off along much of its length, it is better to remove it fully to make it easier to apply the glue. Be careful when prying off to make sure that it does not crack. if it does not come off easily, wedge it away from the base with a pencil or something similar (a chopstick) to give you room to get the glue on both surfaces. Again, be sure to let the glue dry before joining. How long it needs to dry will be explained on the packaging.

With contact cement, no clamping is needed, because it achieves full strength almost immediately.

Comment: Agree about using contact cement with laminate/nonporus materials.  The photo looks like maybe the particle board separated, taking the edge band with it.  If so, I'd use a PVA glue or a poly urethane glue.  Those glues would need clamping.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try with contact cement. The band is off about 40cm of 2 meters. I think if I removed it fully, there would be a small gap at the end. It's either shrunk or was put on with too much tension/not enough glue. @HerrBag How do you mean separated? Some of the wood is stuck to the edge band, but not that much.

Comment: In Europe the laminate sides you can buy by the roll (e.g. to finish countertop cut to size) use a glue that's activated by temperature and normally applied with an iron or something similar. I don't know for sure about factory-applied laminates (including the sides)... but I suspect these are baked as well. Melamine rolls for large surfaces with contact adhesive  (which I think are popular in the US) are nearly impossible to find in Europe. People just buy pre-laminated boards on this side of the pond.